# How to console.log value of a data-attribute in jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

So the console.log part is just to make it easier for me to see the output before I implement this piece of code into my overall solution. I read on stack overflow that you select the data attribute in this way:

```
$("li[data-city*=New York]")
```

But say for instance I want to select all my data attributes which look like this in my html:

```
 data-group='value'
```

So then once I have selected these data attributes, how would I console.log the actual string value part of the data-group attribute.

It may seem like a basic question but a even a simple short answer would help greatly. Regards :)

Comment: `$("li[data-city*=New York]").attr('data-group')`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To select all the elements which have `data-group` attribute, you can loop over the elements selected by the selector `[data-group]`, and in the iteration, get the value of the attribute using the [`data`](https://api.jquery.com/data/) method.

Please see the example below:

```
$('[data-group]').each(function() {
  console.log($(this).data('group'));
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this if you don't know which 'Element' have data-group attribute

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div>
    <ul class="chosen-results" data-group="United States">
      <li class="active-result" data-city="98">New York</li>
      <li class="active-result" data-city="23">Los Angeles</li>
      <li class="active-result" data-city="35">Chicago</li>
      <li class="active-result" data-city="63">Houston</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="chosen-results">
      <li class="active-result" data-city="45">Porto Alegre</li>
      <li class="active-result" data-city="67">Recife</li>
      <li class="active-result" data-city="39">Curitiba</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="chosen-results" data-group="Canada">
      <li class="active-result" data-city="12">Toronto</li>
      <li class="active-result" data-city="26">Montreal</li>
      <li class="active-result" data-city="32">Vancouver</li>
      <li class="active-result" data-city="53">Ottawa</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
<script language="javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

$('body').find('ul').each(function( index ) {

  if($( this ).attr('data-group')){

      console.log( index + ": " + $( this ).text() );

  }

});

</script>
  </body>
</html>
```